# SQL get value based on corresponding min/max(value) from column in another related table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following two tables related by the ID column as the Primary Key. My Goal is to query the values from the "Name" column in Table 1 which correspond to the User_id with the Max and Min "Score" Column Values from Table 2.

```
Table 1:

| ID | Name |
|----|------|
| 1  | Foo  |
| 2  | Bar  |
| 3  | Zoo  |
| 4  | Bar  |
| 5  | Foo  |
| 6  | Zar  |

Table 2:

| ID | Score |
|----|-------|
| 1  | 98    |
| 2  | 67    |
| 3  | 86    |
| 4  | 59    |
| 5  | 75    |
| 6  | 73    |
```

The final output should give me something like this:

```
| Name | Score |
|------|-------|
| Foo  | 98    |
| Bar  | 59    |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
    select name, score 
    from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id
    where 
    score=(select max(score) from t2)
    or 
    score=(select min(score) from t2)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(
SELECT name, score
FROM table1 NATURAL JOIN table2
ORDER BY 2 ASC LIMIT 1
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT name, score
FROM table1 NATURAL JOIN table2
ORDER BY 2 DESC LIMIT 1
)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions:

```
select t1.name, t2.score
from table1 t1
inner join (
    select t2.*, 
        rank() over(order by score) rn_asc, 
        rank() over(order by score desc) rn_desc
    from table2 t2
) t2 on t2.id = t1.id
where 1 in (rn_asc, rn_desc)
```

The idea is to rank records of `table2` by increasing and decreasing `score`, and use that information for filtering. Note that this allows top and bottom ties.